# Hello, i need to show a value from database constantly without reloading page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

i have a table where i display a live price which comes from a cron file that updates every 30seconds or 1 minute, and i have a variable that is filled from that cron job, how do i display it in real-time and make the calculations with php without refreshing the page.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM open_trades WHERE user_id='$session->username' ORDER BY `close_time` DESC ";
                             $result = $db->prepare($sql);
                             $result->execute(); 
                             while ($row = $result->fetch()) {

                                if ($row["type"] == "Buy") {
                                   $profit_c = (float) $row["volume"] * (float) $row["live_price"] - $row["cost"];
                                   $fee = 4.9; 
                                   $profit = $profit_c * $row["laverage"] - $fee;
                                   
                                } 
                                
                                if ($row["type"] == "Sell") { 
                                   $profit_c = (float) $row["volume"] * (float) $row["live_price"] - $row["cost"]; 
                                   $fee = 4.9; 
                                   $profit = $profit_c * $row["laverage"] - $fee; 
                                   $profit_sell = $profit * -1;
                                } 
                                   
                                if ($row["type"] == "Buy") { 
                                   $profit_trd = $profit; 
                                } else { 
                                   $profit_trd = $profit_sell;
                                }
                                   
                                if ($profit_trd >= 0) { 
                                   $col = "profit"; 
                                   } else { 
                                   $col = "loss";
                                } 

                                if ($profit_trd >= 0) { 
                                   $col_b = "#26b276"; 
                                } else { 
                                   $col_b = "#f73e4a";
                                }

                                $open_pl += $profit_trd;
                                   
                                $percentage = ((float) $profit_trd * 100) / (float) $row["cost"]; 

                                echo '<tr style="border-right: 2px solid ' . $col_b . ';" class="d-flex justify-content-between" >'; 
                                echo "<td>" . $row["time"] . "</td>"; 
                                echo "<td>" . $row["asset"] . "</td>"; 
                                echo "<td>" . $row["type"] . "</td>"; 
                                echo "<td>" . (float) $row["volume"] . "</td>"; 
                                echo "<td>1:" . $row["laverage"] . "</td>"; 
                                echo "<td>" . (float) round($row["cost"], 2) . '$</td>'; 
                                echo "<td>" . (float) $row["buy_price"] . '$</td>'; 
                                echo "<td>" . (float) $row["live_price"] . '$</td>'; 
                                echo '<td class="' . $col . '" >' . (float) round($profit_trd, 2) . '$</td>'; 
                                echo "<td>Close Trade </td>"; 
                                echo "</tr>"; }
```

the $row['live_price'] is the variable i need to get it on realtime everytime it updates from the cron job and also did the $profit_trd updates once it updates, or every PHP calculation requires reload?

Thanks and sorry for my amateur questions!?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [*XMLHttpRequest*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) or *[Websocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket)* to make asynchronus calls from your browser without reloading the page.

Please read MDN Web Docs for more information.

[Here](https://www.scriptol.com/ajax/xhr.php) are a great comparison of this.